# Проблема вывода меню в мобильном chrome

Tags: css, css3, google-chrome

Столкнулся с проблемой с меню с бургер меню.

В css перекрестное отображение (если больше 500 отключить 1, отобразить 2 и наоборот)

> css полного меню

```
 @media screen and  (max-width: 499px){
        header{
            display: none;
        }

    }
```

> мини меню

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .nav {
    display: none; }

  #toggle {
    display: none; }

  .hedermin {
    display: none; } }
@media (max-width: 499px) {...}
```

однако мобильный chrome на xiaomi redmi 4x c 360 × 640 показывает сразу 2 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 А другие браузеры отображают нормально [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблемный сайт http://alisa-music.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в media-запросе из-за `screen`

[согласно доке](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media) - screen - экран монитора, чем не является экран телефона

Comment: Вероятно это одна из проблем, но замена  `screen` на `all` не помогла

Comment: попробуйте очистить кеш. проверил с телефона - все ок